# Query to find sub departments vb.net mssacces 97 sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to find subdepartments where they link by description if one is their it should return the id of the one in the table I am using the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Subdeptcode
        ,SubDepartment
    FROM SkechersPricat
    WHERE SubDepartment IN ( SELECT DISTINCT description
                                FROM SubDept )
        AND processed = false
        AND SubDeptCode = 0
```

I need To be able to return the subdeptcode from the sub dept table if one exists if one Doesnt exist create it so I need a query that can account for both condision im using vb.net

Main File looks like the following
[image]

[image: SubDebt Table]

Sub Debt table above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters lets look at your query

```
SELECT DISTINCT Subdeptcode
        ,SubDepartment
    FROM SkechersPricat
    WHERE SubDepartment IN ( SELECT DISTINCT description
                                FROM SubDept )
        AND processed = false
        AND SubDeptCode = 0
```

you are trying to say that `SubDepartment` column needs to be in one of the values of `description` from SubDept table. Unless your `SubDepartment` matches description exactly it will not return anything.

Proper syntax for your query would be using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. By using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` you are saying to get all results from your left table and only records that match in your right table. Thus you still get all the records from main table even if there is no match in `SubDept` table.

Your query will be like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.Subdeptcode
       ,s.SubDepartment
    FROM SkechersPricat s
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SubDept sd
        ON s.SubDepartment = sd.description
    WHERE s.processed = false
        AND s.SubDeptCode = 0
```

What I do see in your screenshot that `GeminDepartmentID` corresponds to `DeptCode` from `SubDept` table. I think you are not joining on correct value.